# Seeking MODIS Land Surface Temperature reference?

Tags: modis, references

Can anyone point me toward an article that converts the LST values on the MODIS LST Image to degrees Celsius?

My purpose is find a reference (article, book or theses) for this formula that converts DN to degree celsius `(C=DN*.02-273.15)`

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focused Q&A format. You have multiple tags on your question - are you using a particular software product? Your question is also unclear -- do you need assistance finding some MODIS documentation?

Comment: thank you so much but this not my aim, my purpose is  find refrence (article, book or theses)for this fermola that convert DN to degree celsius(C=DN*.02-273.15)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but I found this documentation

https://www.usgs.gov/media/videos/getting-started-modis-v6-land-surface-temperature-data-part-2

The Land Surface Temperature data is in degrees Kelvin. You can convert between Kelvin and Celsius through the formula below.

```
K − 273.15 = degC
```

EDIT: after review of other questions on the site (once the OP clarified that they are looking for a reference for multiplying LST by 0.2), I found this answer which referred to the MODIS LST User Guide:

[How do I convert the LST values on the MODIS LST Image to degree celsius](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72524).  The documentation referenced is the actual user guide for Modis LST. https://icess.eri.ucsb.edu/modis/LstUsrGuide/usrguide_mod11.html#sds

Per the linked post, Temperature in °C will be:
`DN * 0.02 - 273.15`

Verify which sensor your data is using just in case they have different calibration values and then look for the appropriate user guide.

Per the Modis 11 Level 2 Product user Guide:

> The effective calibration formula for the "LST" SDS is 
>          LST = the SDS data in uint16 * 0.02, giving a value in the range of 150-1310.7K.

Comment: thank you so much but this not my aim, my purpose is find refrence (article, book or theses)for this fermola that convert DN to degree celsius(C=DN*.02-273.15)

Comment: The answer on this post should work for your project: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72524/how-do-i-convert-the-lst-values-on-the-modis-lst-image-to-degree-celsius.  The documentation referenced is the actual user guide for Modis LST. https://icess.eri.ucsb.edu/modis/LstUsrGuide/usrguide_mod11.html#sds

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this information as well.